# Need guidance! Trying to learn about fetch() and Promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, promise, git-fetch

Basically I'm trying to fetch the URL and URLPaths for two images I've uploaded (to Firebase) using the firebase function /storeImage and JSON.Stringify().

Below is the snippet of code that enables me to fetch data for the ONE image.

```
.then(token => {
    authToken = token;
    return fetch("myappURL/storeImage", 
     {
       method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify({
       image: image.base64
       }),
       headers: {
         Authorization: "Bearer " + authToken,
       }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong, please try again1")
        dispatch(uiStopLoading());
    })
.then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
            return res.json();
        } else {
            throw(new Error());
        }
    })
.then(parsedRes => {console.log(parsedRes);
```

Now I want to fetch data from a second image.

What I gather, from the docs I've read, is that I should use promises for multiple async calls like what I have above. So, shouldn't something like this (see below) work?

```
.then(token => {
    authToken = token;

    let image =  fetch(... image: image.base64 ...);
    let coverImage = fetch(... coverImage: coverImage.base64 ...);

    Promise.all([image, coverImage])
    .then(ress => { ress.forEach(
      res => {
        process( res.json() ); 
   })
})
.catch(err => {...})
.then(res => {...})
.then(parsedRes => {console.log(parsedRes);)
```

Spoiler alert. I tried and it didn't. But I cannot understand why.

Comment: Could you provide some information on the issue, like the error or the result you got?

Comment: I think you should return the *Promise.all* to continue chaining the promises.

Comment: I appreciate the edits done by @gil. But I don't know what should I do next? I tried to press the Next button but it says I need 2k reputation to review suggested edits.

Comment: You're able to use then in the code above because fetch returns a Promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @MarioSantini I tried to answer you questions in the post below, and I've included the full code there as well. Maybe it'll help paint a better picture for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927545/issue-using-fetch-and-promises-to-extract-url-and-url-path-for-multiple-image

Comment: @Reuben I mean you had should add the result of your code, if is not an error, you has should explained why is not ok and what you're expecting. To help people understand your issue. Anyway, you got an answer now and you're not supposed to change your question from now.

Comment: @MarioSantini yeah I saw the answer by Jed only once I posted my answer to you. I tried to explain it here, but I felt it was easier if I showed you and explain using the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you chain promises together, that is, start a new promise inside a `then` callback you need to *return* it.

`Promise.all` returns a single new promise that resolves when *all* of the promises passed to it resolve. In your code above you're neglecting to return it.

E.g. Try running this code which logs `undefined`

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    Promise.all([Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2)])
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

vs this code which logs `[1, 2]`

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    return Promise.all([Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2)])
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'll give this a go.

Comment: [Update] got a new error "Cannot read property 'base64'of underfined", but I count that as progress!